# Safari developer tool search

Tags: javascript, safari

How to search content in all sources in safari developer tool?

I know that in Chrome developer tool the shortcut is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Once in inspect mode you can use the shortkeys <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIF</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or use the search button.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To view source hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> keys.

Comment: Not to view source. To search in all sources.

Comment: For example, I have 10 JavaScript and i want to search for the word : "get".